# Is it possible to drive TestNG test case from Excel?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Let's assume that I have written 4 test cases using TestNG in Selenium, and want to run any 2 test cases with run mode "Yes" provided in Excel. Please let me know, how can I design my code so that any test case with run mode "Yes" gets executed from the list of TestNG test cases.
[image: Screenshot from Excel]

```
public class classname {
    @Test public void testcase1() {
        //Test steps here..
    }
    @Test public void testcase2() {
        //Test steps here..
    }
    @Test public void testcase3() {
        //Test steps here..
    }
    @Test public void testcase4() {
        //Test steps here..
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you consider showing us the dependency of your usecase on Selenium?

Comment: Sure, anything is possible! Have a read through [ask] for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

[`IAnnotationTransformer`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers) should help you:

```
public class MyTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

  private final List<String> activatedTest;

  public MyTransformer() {
      activatedTest = new ArrayList<>();
      // 1. Open Excel file
      // 2. Iterate on lines an add all activated test cases according to the naming convention of test method names (lower case + remove spaces)
      // With you example, the list will containt: "testcase1", "testcase3"
  }

  public void transform(ITest annotation, Class<?> testClass,
      Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    if (activatedTest.contains(testMethod.getName())) {
      annotation.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
      annotation.setEnabled(false);
    }
  }
}
```